# firewalld one-liner define both TCP and UDP

Tags: firewalld

It is for sure possible to define port and protocol in one line, but
how to define both TCP and UDP protocol in one line and not as separate firewalld commands?

```
[root@centos8 /]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2222/tcp/udp
Error: INVALID_PORT: bad port (most likely missing protocol), correct syntax is portid[-portid]/protocol
[root@centos8 /]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2222/tcp-udp
Error: INVALID_PROTOCOL: 'tcp-udp' not in {'tcp'|'udp'|'sctp'|'dccp'}
[root@centos8 /]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2222/tcp|udp
-bash: udp: command not found
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
[root@centos8 /]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2222/tcp,udp
Error: INVALID_PROTOCOL: 'tcp,udp' not in {'tcp'|'udp'|'sctp'|'dccp'}
[root@centos8 /]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2222/tcp udp
usage: see firewall-cmd man page
firewall-cmd: error: unrecognized arguments: udp
[root@centos8 /]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2222/'tcp''udp'
[root@dynatrace /]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2222/tcp udp
usage: see firewall-cmd man page
```

As the last output suggests, the man page was checked but I cannot find such example.

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page you can only specify just one protocol for a port which means running two commands for each port is a necessity.

> The port can either be a single port number or a port range portid-portid. The protocol can **either be** tcp, udp, sctp or dccp.

It's quite rare for services to listen to both TCP and UDP on the same port. I'm only aware of a single service which operates this way and it's DNS.

To make it a one liner, you could use a shell function, e.g.

```bsh
ftu() {
    firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port="$1"/TCP
    firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port="$1"/UDP
}

ftu 1000
```

Comment: You are right, its rare, another service that need both protocols is NFS.

Answer (score 1):

#### It can be done in one line

I know this is a long standing question, but I noticed that no one has provided an answer. I've had a bit of a go at it and the best solution seems to be the use of expansion. It can get quite tricky.

```sh
# simple
firewall-cmd --add-port={80,443}/tcp

# both protocols
firewall-cmd --add-port={80,443}/{tcp,udp}

# can be a bit complex (notice nested brackets)
firewall-cmd --add-port={{80,443}/{tcp,udp},{110,995}/tcp}
```

Then check what you've done :)

```sh
firewall-cmd --list-ports
```

This was just a demonstration to show how both the port and the protocol can be used to create a combination.

#### Services are even better

I've also experimented with `--add-services`, the names of which can be found in the `/etc/services` file. It works too, and it's even more elegant than using ports.

The names and the ports are there, so for example

```sh
grep -E 'http|imap|pop3|smtp|dns|ftp' /etc/services
```

We can also just do something like the following:

```sh
# Simple and readable
firewall-cmd --add-service={http,https}
firewall-cmd --list-services
```

Hopefully it shows how to do this elegantly.

Comment: I agree that it can be done in one line (the man page tells: "This option can be specified multiple times"), but I just have to warn that this answer relies on using the bash (or zsh) shell to get expansion (so won't work in a /bin/sh script where /bin/sh != /bin/bash or /bin/zsh) . OP just asked for a single line, not for a single parameter.

Comment: You're right. It won't work in `/bin/sh`. Good news it it works in `bash` and works in `zsh`.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think the following shells also support filename expansion: `ksh`, `tcsh`, `csh`, `fish`, `dash`.